# SharePoint2013, provider-hosted, remoteAppUrl resolution in Elemets.xml

Tags: 2013, deployment, provider-hosted-app

In my experience when a provider-hosted app is built in VS ~remoteAppUrl gets resolved according to the build profile. The end results is that all webparts' Elements.xml get their page location set at the build time. What if we need to deploy the same .app in a differnet environment where Remote App runs on a different host? Other than rebuilding the app are there any other ways? Can remoteAppUrl be resolved dynamically based on information provided when the app is registerd (appregnew)?